# If $y^{\frac{1}{m}} + y^{\frac{-1}{m}}=2x$, show that $x^2y_{n+2}+(2n+1)xy_{n+1} + (n^2-m^2)y=0$

Tags: calculus

My try :

I have taken $y_1,y_2$ and tried to get a recursive relation between them but couldn't find any pattern. Please help.

Comment: you have not specified what $y_n$ is

Comment: hint : y^(1/m)=a , so , a+1/a =2x,   you can find a (y ^(1/m)) from that by multiplying a , and solve quadratic equation

Comment: I think @Aditya  $y_n$ is $n$th derivative but the textbook doesn't  explicitly mention anything.

Comment: @daryakhosrotash  that looks new ! I'll try solving y^(1/m) using quadratic formula :) thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying derivative $$\frac{y^{\frac1m-1}}my_1-\frac{y^{-\frac1m-1}}my_1=2 \implies\left(y^{\frac1m}-y^{-\frac1m}\right)=\frac{2my}{y_1}$$

Now, $\displaystyle\left(y^{\frac1m}-y^{-\frac1m}\right)^2=\left(y^{\frac1m}+y^{-\frac1m}\right)^2-4$

$\displaystyle\iff \left(\frac{2my}{y_1} \right)^2=\left(2x\right)^2-4$

$$\iff m^2y^2=(x^2-1)y_1^2$$

Applying derivative $\displaystyle m^2(2yy_1)=2xy_1^2+(x^2-1)2y_1y_2$

Cancelling $2y_1$(assuming $\ne0$)

$$\iff m^2y=xy_1+(x^2-1)y_2$$

Now apply [General Leibniz rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have understood till the last line. But not clear on which two functions to pick for leibniz rule. Should I pick the product $xy_1$ ?

Comment: @rsadhvika, See http://wdjoyner.com/teach/calc1-sage/html/node106.html or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Higher_derivatives

Comment: I had used leibniz rule several times before for taking nth derivative of product of funcitons. I'm not able to apply it corretly here, I'm still struggling...

Comment: @rsadhvika, $$\frac{d^n{y_2(x^2-1)}}{dx^n}=(x^2-1)\frac{d^n(y_n)}{dx^n}+\binom n1\frac{d(x^2-1)}{dx^1}\frac{d^{n-1}(y_n)}{dx^{n-1}}+\binom n2\frac{d^2(x^2-1)}{dx^2}\frac{d^{n-2}(y_n)}{dx^{n-2}}+0$$  as $$\frac{d^m(x^2-1)}{dx^m}=0$$ for $m\ge3$

Comment: Why you say m≥3?sir@lab bhattacharjee

Comment: Do u mean $D_3(x^2-1)=0$?